# Extra Long Where/In Statement - Better option?

Tags: sql, excel, where-clause

I've got about 13,000 AccountIDs that I need to pull various data from several data tables using left-joins. The total # of accountIDs is in the millions. I don't have write-access to the server but I was wondering if there was a way I could maybe create a custom/temporary table anyway and do a join to that rather than writing a really, really long Where AccountID in (.....) statement. The accountIDs are currently in a single Excel column so I'd have to get them back in the server somehow.

Thoughts?

Comment: show us the query.

Comment: You could perhaps use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` based on some logic?

Comment: What RDBMS? If SQL Server you don't need any particular permissions to create a `#temp` table.

Comment: There is an amibiguity in your question.  You start by saying the IDs are in various tables, and then you say they are in an Excel file.

Comment: Demand write access. Everything else is a workaround. If you've been given the responsibility, you should be given the authority.

Comment: I agree with @Bohemian. Get write access. This is silly that you're required to do that kind of query like this. Or at the very least, give the list to someone who can add it to a new table and then you can change your query.

Comment: @Joshua - You are asking to be downvoted for wasting peoples time by not putting even your select statement besides tables and data.

Comment: Good question. Office automation has been left behind in the .NET age-- I think VBA is still the most workable solution for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OPENDATASOURCE to access your Excel file, but someone will have to push you the Excel file to the server (not ideal).

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\DataFolder\Documents\TestExcel.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 5.0')...[Sheet1$] ;
```

You can ask your DBA team to install a SQl Server Client on your local machine and set up a linked server to the live server, and you are all set. Ask them to set up a view of the data you need, and give you access to the view. That's all you need, I guess.