# SQL Update Statement with WHERE In clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an extra long where in condition in an SQL statement

```
update ABC_table 
set XXX_column = 10
where YYY_column in ('00-0093149',
... upto 700 values)
```

Is there a better way to do it in Oracle? Maybe something similar to [Extra Long Where/In Statement - Better option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774079/extra-long-where-in-statement-better-option)

without using excel?

Thanks

Comment: You Load all the values in a temp table and work through the values in there

Comment: Not really-- if it's in that many, then you either need to list them in the statement or import them from somewhere. If the number of things you're including greatly outweighs the things you're excluding, you could do a `NOT IN` filter, though.

Comment: If the values come from the database, there is probably a simpler approach.

Comment: It might indicate a db design flaw.

Comment: Using NOT IN will make it even longer :) And yes, the values are from the DB, a column for the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you say *the values are from the DB, a column for the same table*.

Then you can change the query from

```
update ABC_table 
set XXX_column = 10
where YYY_column in ('00-0093149',
... upto 700 values)
```

to

```
update ABC_table abcout
set XXX_column = 10
where exists (select null
              from ABC_table abcin -- the same table
              where abcout.YYY_column = abcin.COLUMN_FOR_THE_SAME_TABLE
                /* and maybe some more restrictions here */);
```

where `COLUMN_FOR_THE_SAME_TABLE` is the column with values.